# easily read file in the www folder with cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

I found a lot of topics on about how to read a simple file located in the www folder. Most of them are old or don't give an example of how to use it. I tried with the cordova file plugin

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```

But i get this error :

```
Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova.file
```

I tried to use the XMLhttpRequest solution, but in the emulator i don't have any result. Here is my code :

```
function xmlLoadFile()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.body.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I have a  on my index.html so i can't figure why i still have a blank page when i run my app.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Here you go: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/07/15/Cordova-Sample-Reading-a-text-file/

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
```

Please refer this url

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Please use any other plugin if you are using ajax. You can use jQuery or similar plugins, otherwise you will end up with lot of code.

Comment: I also tried this plugin, but i can't read a file in the www folder with it, i tried. Impossible to find a working sample code..

Comment: No able to find any issues with your code. But you can try including jquery and load contents using $.get function. Please refer the example found here.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/